# Picard group of positively graded domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} R_i$ be a positively graded noetherian domain with at least one homogeneous element of positive degree. Can I claim that its Picard group is trivial? If not what will happen if $R$ is an affine graded domain over a field $k$.

Comment: Well, not without imposing more constraints. Otherwise, take an affine domain over a field $k$ with non-trivial Picard group, endowed with the trivial grading, for a counterexample.

Comment: Assume $R$ has at least one homogeneous element of positive degree.

Comment: There is a classical result of Murthy that the Picard group of graded normal domains is trivial.

Comment: @YACP: this sounds interesting. do you have a reference?

Comment: @NilsMatthes See Murthy, *Vector bundles over affine surfaces birationally equivalent to a ruled surface*, Lemma 5.1.

Comment: Dear @YACP, this is pretty strong. What are the exact conditions on $R$ please ?

Comment: @QiL'8 $R$ is a finitely generated positively graded normal domain over a field.

Answer (score 0):

Without imposing further conditions on the ring, as commented by user26857, your claim is not true.

$\text{Pic}(k[T^2,T^3])\cong k$, in particular, it is non-trivial see The K-book: an introduction to algebraic K-theory by by Charles Weibel [Chapter I, Example 3.10.1, page 22].